# wordpress, не открывается видео на полный экран через chrome

Tags: html5, wordpress, видео, youtube

именно на chrome не работает полноэкранный режим видео из ютуба, на остальных работает

```
<iframe width="560" height="515" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xtAmdh38WEE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

ставил несколько плагинов, всеравно та же беда, не могу понять в чем дело.

[ссылка](http://sjmania.ru/#section29)

Comment: Chrome Версия 42.0.2311.135 m  -  у меня открывается полнокранно

Comment: @soledar10 поправил ссылку, на отдельной странице работает